# stripe connected accounts subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe connect in "test mode" and i am trying to create a subscription:
In the front end I create a token with the stripe card elements. I am then sending this token, and some other information to my server where i create a subscription object using this method:

```
subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
  customer=customer["id"],
  items=[
    {
      "price": sprice,
    },
  ],
  expand=["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
  application_fee_percent = 5,
  transfer_data={
    "destination": "*******************",
  },
)
```

I then retrieve the payment intent in the latest invoice and get the client secret:

```
client_secret = subscription["latest_invoice"]["payment_intent"].client_secret
```

I then send this client secret back to the front end where i confirm the card payment:

```
var stripe = Stripe('**********************', {
    stripeAccount: "*****************"
  });

stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: {
          token: token,
        },
      },
```

I always get the same error: no such payment intent.
I would love a bit of help :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're creating a subscription using destination charges (without using the `stripeAccount` header), you don't need to set the `stripeAccount` header when you initialize Stripe client-side.

Your current code:

```
var stripe = Stripe('**********************', {
    stripeAccount: "*****************"
  });
```

should be changed to this:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_xxx');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that was it :)